# mySql function return nothing

Tags: mysql

I'm creating this function that supposed to return a random string:

```
create function createRandomString() returns Text
        return concat( 
        char(round(rand()*25)),
        char(round(rand()*25)),
        char(round(rand()*25)),
        char(round(rand()*25)),
        char(round(rand()*25)),
        char(round(rand()*25)),
        char(round(rand()*25)),
        char(round(rand()*25))
    );
```

For some reason this function return nothing... i don't know why..

When i'm using the exact same `concat()` inside a select - it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are returning numeric values between 0 and 25, which are not normal characters to put into a string.  Add 65 to them to start at 'A':

```
create function createRandomString() returns Text
        return concat( 
        char(round(rand()*25+65)),
        char(round(rand()*25+65)),
        char(round(rand()*25+65)),
        char(round(rand()*25+65)),
        char(round(rand()*25+65)),
        char(round(rand()*25+65)),
        char(round(rand()*25+65)),
        char(round(rand()*25+65))
    );
```

You might want to read up on ASCII coding as well, so you better understand what you are doing.